# Pikaday format does not work despite including moment.js

Tags: momentjs, pikaday

I am using the Pikaday Data Picker.  I am unable to override the default format to MM/DD/YYYY.  I have included the Pikaday library and Moment.js but it still does not work.

```
<input id="datepicker" type="text" />

    var picker = new Pikaday(
    {
        field: document.getElementById('datepicker'),
        format : "MM/DD/YYYY",
        firstDay: 1,
        minDate: new Date('2000-01-01'),
        maxDate: new Date(),
        yearRange: [2000,2020]      
    });
```

Here is my fiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/gfinzer/t046bqm2/2/

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You are including moment.js after Pikaday — it needs to be the other way around.

```
<script type="application/javascript" src="moment.js"></script>
<script type="application/javascript" src="pikaday.js"></script>
```

(this code block is only here, because SO otherwise won't let me post the link to JSFiddle without it)

Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/janfoeh/t046bqm2/3/

Comment: It definitely must be in docs, I've spent hours figuring out what's wrong with format.